# Filtering a path querying for N-hop on relationship edges

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to be able to apply filter the output `p` (path) 
Query :

```
match p = (a)-[t*..2]-(b)
return p
```

Here I wish to filter p based on a property on the relationship. But since in the query mentioned above, `t` is a List of relationships, I'm unable to apply filters based on relationship properties.

Example Use case:
Get 2-hop network for node a, where transaction amount > 100.

```
match p = (a)-[t:transaction*..2]-(b)
where edge in t | edge.transaction_amount > 100    
return p
```

What's the way to apply filters based on relationship properties on that list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
MATCH p = (a)-[t*..2]-(b)
WHERE ALL(x IN t WHERE x.transaction_amount > 100)
RETURN p
```

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem! Much appreciated! :D